# How to normalize newline for MVC solution by gitattributes?

Tags: c#, git, model-view-controller

I want to force every team member to use the same newline in solution (C# MVC). I heard it could be done by .gitattributtes file in solution root folder. Everyone use Windows.

My question is what should be content of this file?

Comment: Just check the documentation, or you can read this description from github: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content should looks like it

```
*.cshtml    eol=crlf
*.js        eol=crlf
*.css       eol=crlf
*.cs        eol=crlf
*.csproj    eol=crlf
*.sln       eol=crlf
```